# Vector tiles in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, tiles

I have a vector map (consisting of several polygons) and I would like to create several overlapping tiles. I did the same for a raster map using "split raster". For the vector map, I created an overlapping fishnet (using "buffer" and "feature envelope to polygon") and I tried to use it as split features, but I don't get the correct result (i.e.the overlap is missing).

[image: Vector tiles overlapping]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I think this is a question that would benefit from pictures showing what you input, what you were expecting and what you got as output.  They should be easy to include by using the **edit** button beneath your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you buffer the fishnet layer then you will get the overlap you require.

1- Use Create Fishnet Tool and set its extent to the extent of your vector layer

2- Use measure tool to measure the length of a fishnet cell (for example 20 KM)

3- multiply it by half of overlap (if your overlap is 20% then it becomes 20KM * 0.1), and this is your buffer distance

4- Use Buffer tool with created Fishnet as its input and buffer instance you have calculated in step 3

5- use Split Features tool to split your vector layer!